# pg_dump connection to database failed

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use the pg_dump tool on my local machine. However, when I type pg_dump `database_name` into my terminal window, I get the message that states:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "demo" failed: 
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
```

After receiving this error message, I went into my **postgressql.conf** file (the configuration file for postgres) and set the listen_addresses to `*`. My connection strings appear below:

```
  - Connection Settings -

 #listen_addresses = '*'        # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 20            # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per
# connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directory = ''     # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                # (change requires restart)
```

I then rebooted my machine, hoping that when I type in `pg_dump` in the console, something different would happen. However, even after a restart, I'm still getting the could not connect to server error message (as I have described above).

What steps should I try next in order to remedy this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: **I had two things wrong**, first I hadn't installed pg_dump and the second was the database was turned off!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on Mac OS X, right?

Your PATH is wrong, it's finding `psql`, `pg_dump`, etc from Apple's built-in copy of `psql` PostgreSQL, not the one you installed separately.

Try using `-h /tmp` or `-h localhost`. If that works, that confirms this is the problem. To fix it properly you need to adjust your `PATH` so that the correct PostgreSQL binaries are there first.

(I'm quite annoyed at Apple for bundling PostgreSQL in OS X with the tools on the default system PATH and clashing with any user-installed ones).

Your follow-up comment confirms that this is the problem. You need to run the `pg_dump` from the version of PostgreSQL you installed. Since you didn't say how you installed PostgreSQL, your operating system, or anything else I suggest that you do that by searching for the existing mentions of this problem. A search for something like:

> "OS X" postgresql path

will be informative. So will [this Stack Overflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bosx%5D+postgresql+path).

Alternately, you may explicitly give the path to `pg_dump`. Where it is depends on how you installed PostgreSQL, which you did not mention. It could be `/usr/local/bin/pg_dump`, `/opt/`, etc.

Comment: Craig! This is perfect. Thanks

Comment: `-h localhost`  worked for me in pg_dump on linux (ubuntu 16)